# Yii doesn´t found Bootstrap files with Yiistrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

This is my first post and my first steps in Yii. I have installed the first version of Yii, 1.1. The installation was good but I have some troubles to install Yiistrap extensions. The widgets are fine but their format are wrong.

Browser console said:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -> //localhost/yiiFirst/assets/66939b9c/js/bootstrap.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -> //localhost/yiiFirst/assets/66939b9c/css/bootstrap.css

The file main.php in folder config, the configuration is:

```
// uncomment the following to define a path alias

return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web Application',
// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

 // path aliases
'aliases' => array(
    'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary
    'vendor.twbs.bootstrap.dist' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'),
),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'bootstrap.helpers.*',
    'bootstrap.widgets.*',
    'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'Enter Your Password Here',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
    ),
    
),

// application components
'components'=>array(

    'bootstrap' => array(
        'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
    ),

    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),

    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    

    // database settings are configured in database.php
    'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),

    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),

),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
);
```

And then in the file main.php of views/layouts I have inserted the line:

```
Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
```

I have followed all step from the Yiistrap webpage but I don't find to fix it

Also, I have downloaded the bootstrap files and put in the folder assets but nothing happens.

Could you help me to fix this error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must download bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) and extract to /protected/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist

and you must edit your alias in your config/main.php

```
'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'vendor.twbs.bootstrap.dist' => realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist'),
),
```